# How to remove duplicate value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I want to know how to remove repeated category words from an array.

I have a category name like `<code>hotels</code>` in my database and need to add more hotels in `<code>hotels</code>` category, so the `<code>hotels (category name)</code>` will insert in database with each hotel.
I want to show `<code>hotels (category)</code>` only time in array.

How can I remove multiple duplicate words?

My current code is as below:

```
<?php
    $state = $rst['sp_cat2'];
    $t_typeall = array($state);
    $t = array_filter($t_typeall);
    foreach($t as $t_type){
?>

<h2 class="sub-header" >

<?php
    echo $t_type;
?>

</h2>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, Do you have 2 database having hotels ?

Comment: no , only one database field category is `hotels`
, but when we display results then we want to display category once and products in category below category name, like how many results in `hotels` category

Comment: Why not use distinct in your query to remove duplicate entries from database ?

Comment: i am using `array_unique()` fuction , but not work or how can i use distinct function in query ?

Comment: how are you inserting the value into array from database ?If you using a query then use distinct .Syntax:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks You Sir/Mam, its working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_unique()` function in PHP, this will remove all duplicate values from an array.

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp.

Comment: I am using below code but not works   
`<?php  
$state = $rst['sp_cat2'];  
$t_typeall = array($state);  
$t = array_filter($t_typeall);  
$t2 = array_unique($t);  
foreach($t2 as $t_type){  
?>  

 <h2 class="sub-header"  ><?php echo $t_type;?>  </h2>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct in query to remove duplicates.

Syntax and Documentation::dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html